# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when adding interaction features

Tags: python, interaction, kaggle, feature-engineering

After completing the Feature Engineering course at Kaggle I'm now trying to apply this to the house pricing competition. I have generated interaction features for the categorical variables:

```
interactions = pd.DataFrame(index=X_full.index)

# Iterate through each pair of features, combine them into interaction features
for col1, col2 in itertools.combinations(categorical_cols, 2):
        new_col_name = '_'.join([col1, col2])

        # Convert to strings and combine
        new_values = X_full[col1].map(str) + "_" + X_full[col2].map(str)

        encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        interactions[new_col_name] = encoder.fit_transform(new_values)

interactions_list = [interactions.columns.values.tolist()] + interactions.values.tolist()
```

I converted the dataframe into a list because I want to add them to the categorical and numerical features that I already have, which are in list format:

```
# Keep selected columns only
my_cols = categorical_cols + numerical_cols + interactions_list
X_train = X_train_full[my_cols].copy()
#X_valid = X_valid_full[my_cols].copy()
#X_test = X_test_full[my_cols].copy()
```

But when I try to join these with the other features I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. When I comment out interactions_list from my_cols there is no problem and everything runs fine. Could anyone help me understand this?

Comment: http://net-informations.com/python/iq/unhashable.htm#:~:text=TypeError%3A%20unhashable%20type%3A%20'list'%20usually%20means%20that%20you,lists%20can't%20be%20hashed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. But it's weird to me that this would be the problem since 'categorical_cols' and 'numerical_cols' are also lists...

Comment: What exactly is the change you made?